# google map pathRequest not working for polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dictionary, polyline, elevation

I am working on a website offering a personal list of peaks for mountain lovers.

I am stuck on the function `(pathRequest)` of a Google map `polyline` since ages.

I cannot understand as this code is a copy from a lot of sources and a shame Firefox debug is not acting well with the Google map... getting things worst.

Here's the page :
http://www.mes-sommets.fr/ajouter-un-sommet/

To test, you need to enter `"adresse départ"` (start)`and`"adresse arrivée" (end) + "manuel"`mode in option`"itinéraire"`.

Bug is showing when clicking on `"adresse arrivée"` in autocomplete.

For the two options :

```
- automatique (google map direction service) -- OK
- manuel (polyline) -- KO
```

Then I am calling the same functions :

```
- distance calculation getDistance(path)
- elevation calculation plotElevation(results, status)
```

Mode automatique (google map direction service) :

> ```
> var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
> getDistance(path);
> ```

Mode manuel (polyline) :

> ```
> var polyline_path = polyline.getPath();
> getDistance(polyline_path);
> ```

Function getDistance :

> function getDistance(path) {
>
> var m = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
>   var km = m / 1000;
>
> document.getElementById("ninja_forms_field_34").value = km.toFixed(2) + " km";
>   var pathRequest = {
>         'path': path,
>         'samples': 256      }
>
> elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, plotElevation);
>
> };

Function plotElevation :

> function plotElevation(results, status) {   if (status ==
>   google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
>
> ```
> var deniv_positif = 0;
> var deniv_negatif = 0;
> var elev = results[0].elevation;
> for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
>
>   if ( (results[i].elevation - elev) > 0 ) {
>   deniv_positif = deniv_positif + (results[i].elevation - elev);
>   }
>   else {
>   deniv_negatif = deniv_negatif + (results[i].elevation - elev);
>   }
>
>   elev = results[i].elevation;
>
> }
> document.getElementById("ninja_forms_field_31").value = "+" + deniv_positif.toFixed(0) + " / " + deniv_negatif.toFixed(0) + " m" ;
> ```
>
> } }

Any advice would be great, if I did not put enough code, please tell me. Hope it is OK.

Best regards,

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see is this.

The [DirectionsRoute](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRoute) `overview_path` is *"an **array** of LatLngs"*

The [ElevationService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ElevationService) `getElevationAlongPath` function expects the PathElevationRequest to have an **Array** for its path.

All good so far...

However, the [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) `getPath` function returns an **MVCArray**, not just an **Array**.

Usually they seem pretty interchangeable to me, but this might be one place where they're not.

You could try calling the [getArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) function on the MVCArray to convert it into an **Array** and see if that makes any difference.

```
var polyline_path = polyline.getPath();
getDistance(polyline_path.getArray());
```

Comment: Hello Duncan, that's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Feel free to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as correct if it was useful